# jsPDF - requires deflate.js for compression

Tags: javascript, jspdf, jszip, jscharts

I have a site which makes PDFs containing small images and charts on the client side (they are usually about 2-5 MB in size and all works well) I use jsPDF (1.5.3) to do that.

Today I encountered a problem which never happened before, and I am not quite sure what it even means.

When I try and create the PDF in question I get the following error in my console:

```
There was an error Error: requires deflate.js for compression
    at C (jspdf.min.js:135)
    at Object.I.processPNG (jspdf.min.js:135)
    at Object.x.addImage (jspdf.min.js:50)
    at pdf.self-b4b91c1a4baf7ae76684a8d5c1eb68e250cb9ac1ba550c09d9e01659877bff63.js?body=1:364
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at pdf.self-b4b91c1a4baf7ae76684a8d5c1eb68e250cb9ac1ba550c09d9e01659877bff63.js?body=1:288
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at pdf.self-b4b91c1a4baf7ae76684a8d5c1eb68e250cb9ac1ba550c09d9e01659877bff63.js?body=1:287
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at buildPDF (pdf.self-b4b91c1a4baf7ae76684a8d5c1eb68e250cb9ac1ba550c09d9e01659877bff63.js?body=1:263)
```

So what is exactly the cause of this? Is the PDF too big? Too many pictures / charts?

I would paste the code, but the file is pretty big, and it's just standard PDF building stuff!

Does anyone know what this could be about from the top of their head?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to change compression from 'FAST' to 'NONE' when adding images to PDF, to be more specific :

```js
addImage(imageData, format, x, y, width, height, alias, COMPRESSION <- change this, rotation)
```

Comment: IMHO you should at least a link to the docs or explain how/where exactly to change the compression type.